# Missing name in confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix

In a confusion matrix, what's the name of the percentage of cases I predict as positive out of the total population?

I am in the position of having to use this metric for my project, but I can't find a standard name for it.
If you also see the confusion matrix here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity), the closest definition would be 'prevalence', but in my case I need to use the predicted positives not the actual positives.

Thanks
Gian

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standard term for this; you might find one that's been used before, but I doubt it would be well-known enough to use without defining anyway. If you're referring to it enough to need a succinct phrase, I'd say something like "positive prediction rate" or "predicted prevalence."

Comment: Just like @Dougal, I am not acquainted with a name for such number. Though, 'total positive predictions' seems to me an honest way to define it.